# listbox selected item should highlight with some color

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, selecteditem

I have a `ListBox` with some images.  I want to hightlight the selected item with some color. I am using `WwrapPanel` to display images horizontally with a `ScrollViewer`. Is there any way to solve my problem?

Comment: Maybe want to check spelling and grammar of the title to this question

Answer (score 1):

You should use a ItemContainerStyle with a trigger on the IsSelected property, and in the Trigger you put a setter on the Background property

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got the solution with ur help.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflowTests.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" x:Name="window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <!-- Specifies the Selection style of ListBoxItems. This changes the forced underlay colors from gray to transparent. -->
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Style.Resources>
                <!-- This is the color used if the item is selected and the listbox has focus -->
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Red"/>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <ListBox>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Item 1" />
                <ListBoxItem Content="Item 2" />
                <ListBoxItem Content="Item 3" />
                <ListBoxItem Content="Item 4" />
                <ListBoxItem Content="Item 5" />
                <ListBoxItem Content="Item 6" />
                <ListBoxItem Content="Item 7" />
                <ListBoxItem Content="Item 8" />
                <ListBoxItem Content="Item 9" />
                <ListBoxItem Content="Item 10" />
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>       
    </Grid>
</Window>
```